# Dell Latitude running Windows 7. Touchpad works in some locations but not others?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad

This is the craziest thing that I've experienced three times.  I leave my home office to work at a specific coffee shop and my touchpad is practically disabled.  I can navigate with the "eraser head" within the keyboard but the touchpad is unresponsive.  I can only move it ever so slightly.  If I were to return promptly to my home office, the touchpad works fine.  I've messed with the sensitivity settings to no avail.  Would there be any reason for this?  Wifi, or some other radio interference?  Interferance from the plethora of other laptops in the room?  I really have no idea nor have I seen anything on the web about such a problem.  What's more confusing is that this does not always happen when I'm in this coffee shop.  There are times the touchpad works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sure sounds like electromagnetic interference with a capacitive touch sensor. This could be from the sources you've mentioned, or even a nearby microwave, radio or TV transmitter. [Hopefully, it's not leakage from a microwave oven!]
You could test this with a [Faraday shield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage), if you don't mind some laughs and strange looks from other customers. Make a cover for the touch-pad from metallic window screening, large enough to put your fingers under, and ground it with *short* connections to the laptop, while leaving clearance underneath so that the shield does not touch the pad. This may get you the foil-hat award, or an extra cup of cappuccino if you give an entertaining explanation to the staff. However, if it stops the symptoms, you've identified the issue.